# Funciones con Arrays de Cadenas de texto en C

Tags: array, c, funciones

Buenas tardes a todos,

Estoy intentando practicar con arrays de cadenas de texto y las funciones y/o procedimientos. El caso es que si declaro el procedimiento indicando que le voy a pasar un array de caracteres con los tamaños del array me devuelve errores. La forma en que he hecho funcionar todo esto es la siguiente:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>


#define MAXARRAY 20
#define MAXSTRING 20

void palabra(char[][MAXSTRING], int*);

int main()
{
    char nombre[MAXARRAY][MAXSTRING];
    int numero = 0;

    palabra(nombre, &numero);
    printf("%s\n", nombre[numero-1]);
    
    system("pause");
        
    return 0;
}

void palabra(char nombre[][MAXSTRING], int *numero)
{
    printf("\nDime una palabra: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    fgets(nombre[*numero], MAXSTRING, stdin);
    nombre[*numero][strlen(nombre[*numero])-1] = '\0';
    (*numero)++;
}
```

La verdad es que no se muy bien el porqué. He estado buscando por internet pero no he conseguido aclararme. Tampoco se si esta forma es la correcta. Si alguien me puede indicar el porqué o si me puede indicar la forma correcta se lo agradecería.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: No entiendo el problema.

Comment: Podrías poner, adicional a lo que tienes ahora mismo, el código que te da problemas?

Comment: `char nombre[MAXSTRING];` es una declaración de una cadena.

`int numeros[MAXARRAY];` es una declaración de una tabla de enteros. Lo he puesto en plural.

`char nombres[MAXARRAY][MAXSTRING];` es una declaración de una tabla de cadenas. En plural.

Answer (score 0):

Una tabla (*array*) está definida por dos parámetros: su tamaño y el tipo de sus elementos. En C, tu puedes definir el tipo de los elementos, pero no puedes imponer al subprograma el número de elementos de la tabla. Es así porqué en la mayoría de los casos prácticos, este número no es fijo.

En C no puedes pasar una tabla como parámetro; se pasa la posición del 1º elemento, pero no dice cuando elementos son. Siempre que escribas `xxx[]` como argumento, el compilador lo transforma en `*xxx`. Y no considera (ni autoriza) poner el tamaño de la tabla.

Entonces cuando tu programa llama a `palabra()`, el número de elementos en la tabla `nombre` puede ser cualquiera, no tiene que ser `MAXARRAY`. Y si el subprograma `palabra` necesita saber este número, hay que decírselo con un argumento suplementario.